# error: unable to index file 'src/hoc/Aux.js'

Tags: git, github

I created a new repository in GitHub and tried to add my react project to that repository. There, when I was trying to `git add .`, below error appeared.

```
error: open("src/hoc/Aux.js"): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file 'src/hoc/Aux.js'
fatal: adding files failed
```

`git status` gave the below status:

```
PS F:\ReactTutorialsTest\burger-builder-project> git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        README.md
        debug.log
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        public/
        src/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So, how am I supposed to make this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the file name to another name except **Aux**. So, it did work. Using a different file name could correct the error!